# Global ngResource base

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I have multiple factories in my angular service located in different js file. And there is common base of all the queries:

1) Authorization: Bearer token (header) (required after login) 
2) AccessDateTime, UserIPAddress (required before login)
3) AccessDateTime, UserIPAddress, UserID (required after login)

Now, I find that it is very tedious to repeat this on each of the resource. How could i make a base for this? I thought that this is something very common but i could not found any documentation on this. Something like jquery.AjaxSetup().

Default Code

```
angular.module('app.test').factory('Test', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return {
            resource1: $resource(
                url: 'test1/:testId/:AccessDateTime/:UserIPAddress',
                headers: { Authorization: Bearer token},
                params: { testId: '@_id', AccessDateTime:'@AccessDateTime', UserIPAddress: '@UserIPAddress' }
            }),
            resource2:  return $resource(
                url: 'test2/:testId/:AccessDateTime',
                params: { testId: '@_id', AccessDateTime:'@AccessDateTime' }
            });
        }
    }
]);
```

Code after base resource implemented(Illustration only)

```
angular.module('app.base').factory('FactoryBase'), ['resource',
    function($resource) {}
        if (resource need authorization) {
            auto append header, AccessDateTime, UserIPAddress
        } else if (resource do not need authorization) {
            auto append AccessDateTime
        }

        // depending on attribute set with authorize: true/false
    }
]);

angular.module('app.test').factory('Test', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        require('FactoryBase'),
        return {
            resource1: $resource(
                url: 'test1/:testId',
                authorize: true
            }),
            resource2: $resource(
                url: 'test2/:testId',
                authorize: false
            }),
    }
]);
```

Comment: You could look at how Backbone extends classes https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1858

Answer (score 0):

Put modifier functions in your factory:

```
angular.module('app.test').factory('Test', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        var defaultConfig1 = {
             url: 'test1/:testId/:AccessDateTime/:UserIPAddress',
             headers: { Authorization: Bearer token},
             params: { testId: '@_id', 
                       AccessDateTime:'@AccessDateTime',
                       UserIPAddress: '@UserIPAddress' 
                     }
        };
        var defaultConfig2 = {
            url: 'test2/:testId/:AccessDateTime',
            params: { testId: '@_id',
                      AccessDateTime:'@AccessDateTime'
                    }
        };
        function mod1(arg) {
            var obj = defaultConfig1;
            //modify config
            return obj;
        };
        function mod2(arg) {
            //modify and return defaultConfig
        };
        return {
            resource1: $resource(defaultConfig1),
            resource2: $resource(defaultConfig2).
            modified1: function (arg) {
                return $resource(mod1(arg));
            },
            modified2: function (arg) {
                return $resource(mod2(arg));
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

You have the full power of JavaScript to modify the configuration objects as you please before returning them.